# How to set up accounts to issue reverse (credit) an event payment

Tags: civicontribute, 4.7.31

I have Civicontribute set up to invoice conference delegates, but can't work out how to set up the accounts to issue credit notes for booking changes or cancellations.

I get an error "This financial account cannot have 'Credit/Contra Revenue Account is' relationship" no matter which account I try to assign.

My setup has the following:

- Income Account is    Event Fee   Revenue (INC)
- Accounts Receivable Account is    Accounts Receivable   Asset (AR)
- Expense Account is    Banking Fees   Expenses (EXP)
- Cost of Sales Account is Premiums    Cost of Sales (COGS)
- Deferred Revenue Account is  Deferred Revenue - Event Fee Liability (OCLIAB)

My accounts setup simply reverses the credit against the Events Fee income account.  Can someone give me some guidance please?

Comment: I've created a bug report at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/financial/issues/17